# Powershell + MegaCLI - Making the output more readable

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Looking for some help with making an output from a MegaCli command a bit more readable.

The output is:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\8-04-07_MegaCLI\Win_CliKL_8.04.07\MegaCliKL -LDInfo -Lall -aAll


Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :OS
RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 558.375 GB
Mirror Data         : 558.375 GB
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives    : 2
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAdaptive, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAdaptive, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disk's Default
Encryption Type     : None
Bad Blocks Exist: No
Is VD Cached: Yes
Cache Cade Type : Read Only


Virtual Drive: 1 (Target Id: 1)
Name                :Storage
RAID Level          : Primary-0, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 7.275 TB
Parity Size         : 0
State               : Optimal
Strip Size          : 64 KB
Number Of Drives    : 4
Span Depth          : 1
Default Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAdaptive, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Current Cache Policy: WriteBack, ReadAdaptive, Direct, No Write Cache if Bad BBU
Default Access Policy: Read/Write
Current Access Policy: Read/Write
Disk Cache Policy   : Disk's Default
Encryption Type     : None
Bad Blocks Exist: No
Is VD Cached: Yes
Cache Cade Type : Read Only



Exit Code: 0x00
```

The command I'm using is:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\8-04-07_MegaCLI\Win_CliKL_8.04.07\MegaCliKL -LDInfo -Lall -aAll
```

How can I make that information a bit more readable?

I only actually need: Name, Raid Level, Size, Number of drives, State, and Span Depth.

It has to be doable in just powershell.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Zack

Comment: You will need to parse the output of the executable to select only the data you want.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what the desired output should look like?

Comment: `(MegaCliKL -LDInfo -Lall -aAll) -match "Name|Raid Level|Size|Number of drives|State|Span Depth"`

Comment: @josefZ Thank you! That's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If *"a bit more readable"* means *"reduce output merely to lines starting with listed items"*:

```
$MegaCliKL = & C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\8-04-07_MegaCLI\Win_CliKL_8.04.07\MegaCliKL -LDInfo -Lall -aAll
$listedItems = '^\s*Name',
               'Raid Level',
               'Size',
               'Number of drives',
               'State',
               'Span Depth' -join '|^\s*'
$MegaCliKL -match $listedItems |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ( $_ -match '^\s*Name' ) {''} # line separator
        $_
    }
```

**Output**:

```
Name                :OS
RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 558.375 GB
State               : Optimal
Number Of Drives    : 2
Span Depth          : 1

Name                :Storage
RAID Level          : Primary-0, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
Size                : 7.275 TB
State               : Optimal
Number Of Drives    : 4
Span Depth          : 1
```